WSO2 TOTP not working as port 9443 is getting appended to the url
I have wso2 installed in  2 nodes and each node have apache2 running on port 443 and wso2 running on 9443/9763 port. There is a load balancer for the nodes.
While implementing 2FA with Totp when user logs in for the first time he has to scan a  QRcode and then give the verification code in the next (Totp.jsp) page .
This works fine as no 9443 port is appended to the url while the process .
After user has logged in the first time ,from the second time onwards totp.jsp page prompts with port number 9443 appended to the url.
This gives an error of method not allowed /page is taking too long to respond.
Can anyone please help as how we can resolve the issue so that port 9443 does not get appended to the url.

Did you configure a proxy_context_path in the identity server?

where do i need to configure that..I configured it at tomcat
